# Estimating integral of product of terms $\cos(t\log p)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, moments

I would like to prove the following proposition from A. Harper's paper "[Sharp conditional upper bound for moments of the Riemann Zeta Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.4618.pdf)"

> **Proposition.**
>   Let $T$ be large and let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$, where $p_i$ are distinct primes and $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $i$. Then
>   $$ \int_T^{2T}\prod_{i=1}^r\cos(t\log p_i)^\alpha_i dt = Tf(n)+\mathcal{O}(n)$$
>   where $f(n)=0$ if any of the exponents $\alpha_i$ is odd, and otherwise
>   $$ f(n)=\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}\frac{\alpha_i!}{((\alpha_i/2)!)^2}$$

He says that this is a slight variant of Lemma 4 from [Radzwill's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5092.pdf) on Selberg's central limit theorem, noting that the error ter there is estimated quite generously, and can actually be taken a $\mathcal{O}(n)$.
The proof goes on as follows: consider primes $q_1,\dots q_k\leq x$ with $q_1\cdots q_k=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}=n$. Since $\cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$ we have
$$
\cos(t\log p_i)^{\alpha_i}=\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}(e^{it\log p_i}+e^{-it\log p_i})^{\alpha_i}=\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i\choose \alpha_i/2}+\sum_{\substack{0\leq \ell\leq \alpha_i \\ \ell\neq\alpha_i/2}}\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i\choose \ell}e^{i(\alpha_i-2\ell)t\log p_i}
$$
Hence
$$
\int_T^{2T}\prod_{i=1}^r\cos(t\log p_i)^\alpha_i dt = \int_T^{2T}\prod_{i=1}^r\left(\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i\choose \alpha_i/2}+\sum_{\substack{0\leq \ell\leq \alpha_i \\ \ell\neq\alpha_i/2}}\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i\choose \ell}e^{i(\alpha_i-2\ell)t\log p_i}\right)
$$
which equals to
$$
Tf(n)+\sum_{\substack{0\leq \ell_i\leq_{\alpha_i} \\ \text{for all } 1\leq i\leq r\\ \text{not all }\ell_i=\alpha_i/2}}\int_T^{2T}\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i\choose \ell}e^{i(\alpha_i-2\ell)t\log p_i}dt
$$
He then says that the number of terms in the sum is $\leq(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_r+1)\leq 2^{\alpha_1}\cdots 2^{\alpha_r}=2^k$ where $k=\alpha_1+\cdots\alpha_r$. Moreover each of these terms is of the form
$$
\int_T^{2T} \gamma e^{it(\beta_1\log p_1+\cdots
 \beta_r \log p_r)}dt$$
with $|\gamma|\leq 1$ and integers $|\beta_i|\leq\alpha_i$. He then claims that $\beta_1\log p_1+\cdots
 \beta_r \log p_r\gg x^{-k}$ and therefore, using that $\int e^{cit}=-\frac{ie^{cit}}{c}+constant$ and that $|\gamma|\leq 1$ we get that 
$$
\int_T^{2T} \gamma e^{it(\beta_1\log p_1+\cdots
 \beta_r \log p_r)}dt\ll x^k$$
therefore the sum actually contributes at most $\mathcal{O}(2^kx^k)$.
My question is: how do I go from $\mathcal{O}(2^kx^k)$ to $\mathcal{O}(n)$?
I guess the bound $(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_r+1)\leq 2^{\alpha_1}\cdots 2^{\alpha_r}=2^k$ could be improved. I don't know how to show the bound
$$\beta_1\log p_1+\cdots
 \beta_r \log p_r\gg x^{-k}$$
maybe this can be improved as well.
The only other bound used is $|\gamma|\leq 1$ where $\gamma$ is product of factors of the form $\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i\choose \ell}$. Using Stirling's approximation for the factorial I have
$$
\frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i \choose \ell}\leq \frac{1}{2^{\alpha_i}}{\alpha_i \choose \alpha_i/2}\sim\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi\alpha_i}}
$$
hence this bound is good.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hey so write \sum \beta_i \log{p_i} =: \log{u} with u\in \Q and note that by complex conjugating the integral if necessary wlog u > 1 [u\neq 1 since not all \beta_i = 0]. now just bound the denominator of u to see that u > 1 + 1/denominator, QED that part (here denominator\leq n, in fact \leq n^{1/2} is also true: \log{numerator*denominator} = \sum |\beta_i| \log{p_i}\leq \log{n}). otherwise I think you’re maybe just confused by notation? I couldn’t entirely follow what you wrote, e.g. what role do the q_i play given that they don’t appear again, why is there an x^k and not an n, etc.

Comment: Hi! what I would like to prove is that $(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_r+1)\int_T^{2T}\gamma e^{it(\beta_1\log p_1+\cdots+\beta_r\log p_r)}dt\ll n$. The $p_i$ denote the distinct prime factor of $n$ whereas the $q_i$ are all the prime factors dividing $n$ with multiplicity.

Comment: I can write $\beta_1\log p_1+\cdots+\beta_r\log _r=\log \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\beta_i}$. WLOG I can assume $u=\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\beta_i}>1$. Since all $\beta_i$ are bounded in absolute value by $\alpha_i$ I indeed get that the denominator of $u$ is bounded by $n^{1/2}$ (as $u$ must be greater than 1). If I now wirte $u=\frac{r}{s}$ with $(r,s)=1$ I have that $u>1+\frac{1}{s}$. Now using that  $\log(u)>log(1+1/s)>\frac{1/s}{1+1/s}=\frac{1}{s+1}$ I get that $\beta_1\log p_1+\cdots+\beta_r\log _r\gg n^{-1/2}$

Comment: yep! except that should be \gg n^{-1/2}.

Comment: sure, sorry for the typo!

Comment: How do I deal with the factor $(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_r+1)$?

Comment: well that’s why i added the note about the n^{1/2} —- i couldn’t exactly understand the bound you wanted, but anyway if you want a final bound of n certainly using d(n) << n^\eps is sufficient.

Comment: oh right! thank you very much for your help!

Comment: np!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(char min)